# indexOf если ничего не нашло

Tags: jquery

Есть некий код который ищет на странице похожие слова.
И он отлично работает, единственное нужно прописать условие если ничего не нашло то к примеру алерт показать. Помогите пожалуйста код ниже

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#search").keyup(function(){
       _this = this;
        var d = $(".services-title");
       $.each($(".cat-services"), function() {

           if($(this, d).text().toLowerCase().indexOf($(_this).val().toLowerCase()) === -1) {
            $(this, d).hide();
               $(this).hide();
           } else {
            $(this, d).show();
               $(this).show();
           }  

       });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$("#search").keyup(function() {
  var reg = new RegExp( $(this).val(), 'ig' ); // Флажок 'i' = игнорирует case
  var d = $(".services-title");
  var match = 0; 

  $(".cat-services").each(function() {
    if ( $(this, d).text().match(reg) ) {           
      $(this, d).show();
      match++;
    } else {        
      $(this, d).hide();
    }
  });

  if( match ){
    alert('Найдено совпадений: ' + match + ' штук.');
  } else {
    alert('Ничоси! Ничего не найдено.');
  } 
});
```

Это при условии, что alert здесь - условность. В реальном коде задолбает вылетать, пока введут полное слово (или надо делать поиск при клике, а не keyup)

Comment: Спасибо большое, а можно еще подсказать как сделать правильно что бы категорию показывало там где нашло совпадение? спасибо

Comment: @FACT Channel оно же ищется через `.each...`  if( ...match) { // $(this) - это и будет элемент, в котором найдено совпадение. }`